# A simple interpreter not functioning well

Tags: python, interpreter

I found a web site [[Python: Writing a Compiler and Interpreter in 160 lines of code]](http://www.jroller.com/languages/entry/python_writing_a_compiler_and) which implement a simple interpreter, i'm very impressed by the code and want to improve it, below is the modified version of the source:

```
#****************** Grammer ************************
# stmtlist   := (statement)*
# 
# statement  :=    'if' condition ('{')? stmtlist ['else' stmtlist] '}'
#                | 'while' condition ('{')? stmtlist '}'
#                | variable '=' expression
#                | variable '+=' expression
#                | variable '-=' expression
#                | variable '*=' expression
#                | variable '/=' expression
#                | 'print' expression
# 
# condition  := expression ('=='|'!='|'>'|'<'|'>='|'<=') expression
# 
# expression := term ('+'|'-' term)*
# 
# term       := factor ('*'|'/' factor)*
# 
# factor     := variable|digit

#****************** Lexer ************************

tokenlist = []
currtoken = ("", "", 0) # token, identifier name, value
keywords = set(["while", "if", "else", "print", 
                "=", "==", "!=", ">", ">=", "<", "<=", 
                "+", "-", "*", "/", "+=", "-=", "*=", "/=",
                "{", "}"]) # '}' end 'while' and 'if'
symboltable = dict()

def nextToken():
    global currtoken, symboltable
    if(len(tokenlist) > 0):
        s = tokenlist.pop(0)
        if s in keywords:
            currtoken = (s, "", 0)
        elif s.isdigit():
            #currtoken = ("digit", "", int(s))
            currtoken = ("digit", "", float(s))
        elif s.isalnum():
            symboltable[s] = 0
            currtoken = ("variable", s, 0)
        else:
            print("syntax error: " + s)
    else:
        currtoken = ("", "", 0)

def consume(expected):
    if currtoken[0] == expected:
        nextToken()
    else:
        print("expected " + expected + " not found")

#****************** Parser ************************

def parseFile(filename):
    inputfile = open(filename, "r")
    inputstring = inputfile.read()
    global tokenlist
    tokenlist = inputstring.split()
    nextToken()

    pgm = doStatementList()
    return execStatementList(pgm)

def doStatementList():
    stmts = []
    newstmt = []

    while currtoken[0] in ["while", "if", "print", "variable"]:
        if currtoken[0] == "while":
            # ["while", [condition], ['{'] [statementlist], '}']
            consume("while")
            newstmt = ["while"]
            newstmt.append(doCondition())
            if currtoken[0] == "{":
                consume("{")
            newstmt.append(doStatementList())
            #consume("endwhile")
            consume("}")
        elif currtoken[0] == "if":
            # ['if' [condition] [statementlist] ['{'] [['else' statementlist]] '}']
            consume("if")
            newstmt = ["if"]
            newstmt.append(doCondition())
            if currtoken[0] == "{":
                consume("{")
            newstmt.append(doStatementList())
            if currtoken[0] == "else":
                consume("else")
                newstmt.append(doStatementList())
            #consume("endif")
            consume("}")
        elif currtoken[0] == "print":
            # ["print", [expression]]
            consume("print")
            newstmt = ["print"]
            newstmt.append(doExpression())
        elif currtoken[0] == "variable":
            # ["=", [variable], [expression]]
            variable = [currtoken[1]]
            nextToken()
            if currtoken[0] == "=":
                consume("=")
                newstmt = ["="]
            elif currtoken[0] == "+=":
                consume("+=")
                newstmt = ["+="]
            elif currtoken[0] == "-=":
                consume("-=")
                newstmt = ["-="]
            elif currtoken[0] == "*=":
                consume("*=")
                newstmt = ["*="]
            elif currtoken[0] == "/=":
                consume("/=")
                newstmt = ["/="]
            newstmt.append(variable)
            newstmt.append(doExpression())
        else:
            print("invalid statement: " + currtoken[0])
        stmts.append(newstmt)
    return stmts

def doCondition():
    exp = doExpression()
    # ["==|!=|>|<|>=|<=", [left side], [right side]]
    if currtoken[0] in ["==", "!=", ">", ">=", "<", "<="]:
        retval = [currtoken[0]]
        retval.append(exp)
        nextToken()
        retval.append(doExpression())
    else:
        print("expected == or != not found")
    return retval

def doExpression():
    term = doTerm()
    # carry the term in case there's no +|-
    exp = term
    # ["+|-", [left side], [right side]]
    while currtoken[0] in ["+", "-"]:
        exp = [currtoken[0]]
        nextToken()
        exp.append(doExpression())
        exp.append(term)
    print("exp=", exp)
    return exp

def doTerm():
    factor = doFactor()
    term = factor
    # ["*|/", [left side], [right side]]
    while currtoken[0] in ["*", "/"]:
        term = [currtoken[0]]
        nextToken()
        term.append(doTerm())
        term.append(factor)
    print("term=", term)
    return term

def doFactor():
    if currtoken[0] == "variable":
        retval = currtoken[1]
        nextToken()
    elif currtoken[0] == "digit":
        retval = currtoken[2]
        nextToken()
    return [retval]

#****************** Interpreter ************************

stack = []

def execStatementList(pgm):
    for stmt in pgm:
        execStatement(stmt)

def execStatement(stmt):
    if stmt[0] == "while":
        # ["while", [condition], [statementlist]]
        execCondition(stmt[1])
        while stack.pop():
            execStatementList(stmt[2])
            execCondition(stmt[1])
    elif stmt[0] == "if":
        # ['if' [condition] [statementlist] [['else' statementlist]] 'endif']
        execCondition(stmt[1])
        if stack.pop():
            execStatementList(stmt[2])
        elif len(stmt) == 4:
            execStatementList(stmt[3])
    elif stmt[0] == "=":
        execExpression(stmt[2])
        symboltable[stmt[1][0]] = stack.pop()
    elif stmt[0] == "+=":
        execExpression(stmt[2])
        symboltable[stmt[1][0]] =  symboltable[stmt[1][0]] + stack.pop()
    elif stmt[0] == "-=":
        execExpression(stmt[2])
        symboltable[stmt[1][0]] =  symboltable[stmt[1][0]] - stack.pop()
    elif stmt[0] == "*=":
        execExpression(stmt[2])
        symboltable[stmt[1][0]] =  symboltable[stmt[1][0]] * stack.pop()
    elif stmt[0] == "/=":
        execExpression(stmt[2])
        symboltable[stmt[1][0]] =  symboltable[stmt[1][0]] / stack.pop()
    elif stmt[0] == "print":
        execExpression(stmt[1])
        print("output:" + str(stack.pop()))
    else:
        print("invalid statement")

def execCondition(cond):
    # ["==|!=|>|<|>=|<=", [left side], [right side]]
    execExpression(cond[1])
    execExpression(cond[2])

    a = stack.pop()
    b = stack.pop()
    if cond[0] == "==":
        stack.append(a == b)
    elif cond[0] == "!=":
        stack.append(a != b)
    elif cond[0] == ">":
        stack.append(b > a)
    elif cond[0] == ">=":
        stack.append(b >= a)
    elif cond[0] == "<":
        stack.append(b < a)
    elif cond[0] == "<=":
        stack.append(b <= a)


def execExpression(exp):
    if len(exp) == 3:
        execExpression(exp[1])
        execExpression(exp[2])
        if exp[0] == "+":
            a = stack.pop()
            b = stack.pop()
            stack.append(a + b)
        elif exp[0] == "-":
            a = stack.pop()
            b = stack.pop()
            stack.append(a - b)
        if exp[0] == "*":
            a = stack.pop()
            b = stack.pop()
            stack.append(a * b)
        elif exp[0] == "/":
            a = stack.pop()
            b = stack.pop()
            stack.append(a / b)
    else:
        #if type(exp[0]) == int:
        if type(exp[0]) == float:
            stack.append(exp[0])
        else:
            stack.append(symboltable[exp[0]])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parseFile("./simpleScript.txt")
```

And below is the `simpleScript.txt` file:

```
d = 2 + 5 * 3 - 2 * 4 + 5
print d
```

The expected result should be `14.0`, but i got `4.0`. I know the problem is in function `doExpression` and `doTerm`, but i cannot figure it out how to correct it, anyone please help me.

Comment: In (output): `('exp=', ['+', ['-', ['+', [5.0], ['*', [4.0], [2.0]]], ['*', [3.0], [5.0]]], [2.0]])` you see observe that the 2*4 is added to 5 prior to do the substraction.

Comment: I see the result, but i cannot figure it out how to correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only idea, I got right now consists of doing of special case for `-`. What I mean is that you can consider it as a `+`, if you multiple by `-1` the expression inside of it (you have to do it in the next `doExpression`, so i'm passing a boolean).

Change your `doExpression()` for (I'm sorry it's a bit ugly, maybe someone will propose an other solution):

```
def doExpression(_b = True):
    term = doTerm()
    if _b == False:
        tp = ['*']
        tp.append([-1.0])
        tp.append(term)
        term = tp
    # carry the term in case there's no +|-
    exp = term
    # ["+|-", [left side], [right side]]
    while currtoken[0] in ["+", "-"]:
        exp = ['+']
        if currtoken[0] == '+':
            nextToken()
            exp.append(doExpression())
        else: # '-'
            nextToken()
            exp.append(doExpression(_b = False))
        exp.append(term)

    print("exp=", exp)
    return exp
```

Comment: You are right, this way the expression can be interpreted without problem, thank you very much!